# Ionic 3 popup color change

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I need to change the `css` of my alert popup, mean I want to change the title color to white and the background color to grey. Can any one help how this is possible ? Thanks.

[image: Popup color change white to any other]

```
 presentPrompt() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Add Your Question',
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'would',
        placeholder: 'Would You ',
      },
      {
        name: 'rather',
        placeholder: 'Rather'
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Add',
        role: 'add',
        handler: data => {
          this.wouldquestion = data.would;
          this.ratherquestion = data.rather;
          this.afd.list("Questions/").push({
            would:this.wouldquestion,
            rather:this.ratherquestion,
            ratherclick:this.ratherclicks,
            wouldclick:this.wouldclicks
          });
        }
      },
          ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting background of entire popup or only of title to change?

Comment: yes its possible . are you want to only this popup or all apps popup

Comment: only this popup . change the background color of entire popup

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
add app.scss
.alertCustomCss {
        color: #e37b26; // text color for basic alerts
        button {
            color: white !important;
            background-color: color($colors, primary, base) !important;
        }
        .alert-message {
            color: #e37b26; // text color for confirm alerts
            // background-color: color($colors, primary, base) !important;
        }
        .alert-sub-title {
          color: #e37b26; // text color for confirm alerts
        //   background-color: color($colors, primary, base) !important;
        }
        .alert-wrapper {
            background-color: color($colors, gray, base);
        }
        .alert-input {
            color: black;
        }
      }
```

Comment: cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'